Need a cloud backup solution with the following three features:

Needs to be schedulable, say to run once a week, or alternatively as a continuous background syncing daemon. Either way, I need the backup operation to be as recent a mirror of my data as possible.
Needs to run on Windows 10 and recent versions of Android.
Provides, as near as is possible, a full backup of the C: drive and internal flash memory, respectively.

Ideally, the solution will require not too much networking/cloud knowledge to set up. I am a developer by trade and have a little bleedover knowledge in these areas but it's far from a forte. Obviously willing to pay for the service, I'm thinking in the order of 1 or 2 TB. I've been using Acronis for a year's subscription which is due to renew, and while it's fine for Windows, the sticking point has been the rather poor coverage of the Android app, backing up only basic stuff like messages and media files. This issue seems to be a common thread with Android solutions, hence this question.
One last point that just came to me - I'm willing to consider separate solutions for each OS, as long as the combined cost isn't prohibitive.

So you'd like for it to be self-hosted? If so, you should include it in requirements.

@Destroy666 nope, where did you get that idea from?

"Ideally, the solution will require not too much networking/cloud knowledge to set up"

@Destroy666 I'm referring to configuration of a client to connect to pre-existing externally hosted services.
